# Делимся впечатлениями о GUI-биндингах для python (PyQt, Gtk, etc...)

Tags: python, gui

Привет всем! 
Хочу написать небольшое приложение для управления порталом на python, но таким образом, чтобы оно работало НЕ в браузере, т.е., мне нужно десктопное приложение. В общем, с разработкой GUI приложений на python у меня опыта почти нет(Несколько месяцев назад писал небольшое приложение в связке с GTK, создающим иконку в трее, и по таймеру выполняющее определенные действия, но что-то не доставило мне это GTK).

Раньше прогал на C#, delphi. 
python выбрал, потому что нужна кроссплатформенность, да и просто сам язык очень нравится.

Хотелось бы выслушать мнения людей, работавших с несколькими UI toolkit, и которые могут сравнить один тулкит с другим.

спасибо.

Comment: А не сделать ли этот вопрос [Общим][1] ?

[1]:http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading19

Answer (score 3):

Я вот плюсану за Qt. Только PyQt нельзя использовать в коммерческих проектах. Зато можно использовать [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide). Полностью совместима с PyQt.

Сам долго мучался. По какой-то непонятной причине, несмотря на миллион хвалебных слов в сторону Qt, мне этот фреймворк априори почему-то не нравился.

Полагаю, это из-за того, что на C++ сперва должен отработать препроцессор. Мне это казалось "нечистым" C++ :)

Как только начал пользоваться PyQt(и PySide) всё это прошло. Синтаксис Python подходит для идей Qt как нельзя лучше.

Отличная документация, отличная архитектура фреймворка, кто-то даже говорит, что работает быстрее, чем wxPython.

А вот вам еще целый документ, который посвящен сравнению фреймворков:
[PyGTK, PyQT, Tkinter and wxPython](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fojs.pythonpapers.org%2Findex.php%2Ftpp%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F61%2F57&ei=m5zvUbawNanZ4ASLuoG4Aw&usg=AFQjCNHc4LTSGwn89NE-iyUunH4eJRKIXg&sig2=GG5vGsu8VkdTw1td0ZFJeg&cad=rja)

Answer (score 2):

Мой голос за [wxwidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)
Выглядит нативно на всех платформах, кросплатформенно. wxPython есть.

Answer (score 2):

Пишу на wxPython. В целом достаточно неплохо, да и примеров масса в интернете: [Getting Started](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started) и на [zetcode](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/) например. Единственное, когда порой сталкиваешься с какой-нибудь тонкостью, возникают проблемы. Вот например хотел использовать для SpinButton акселератор, т.е. при долго зажатой кнопке up значение SpinButton быстрее бы увеличивалось. "Из коробки" этого нет, ну и т.д. А так вообще реализовать средненький GUI годится.

Answer (score 2):

PyQT - полюбил на века с первых строк. Советую. Однако он требует установку либ фреймфорка, зато Tkinter будет работать из коробки

Comment: tkinter из коробки не работает. К нему dll либы надо доустановить(по крайней мере на linux) К тому же он кривой и известен только в питоне

Answer (score 0):

PyQt - очень хорошая штука и очень мощная, на питон портирована один в один практически, позволяет строить красивые и функциональные GUI, плюс ко всему Qt сам по себе очень хорош со всеми своими библиотеками. Ну, или можно взять Tkinter из стандартной библиотеки, простой как три копейки и не нужно ничего устанавливать дополнительно.